# Event not receive in professional email by graph API

Tags: php, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I have created GRAPH API code in the Laravel with a library
this is a perfectly event send and receive in the outlook email address
but not receive in some professional emai address
see my code below for the Graph api

```
$event = new Event();
$event->setSubject($subject);

$body = new ItemBody();
$body->setContentType(new BodyType("html"));

$body->setContent($description);

$event->setBody($body);

$start = new DateTimeTimeZone();
$start->setDateTime($startTimes);
$start->setTimeZone("America/New_York");
$event->setStart($start);

$end = new DateTimeTimeZone();
$end->setDateTime($endTimes);
$end->setTimeZone("America/New_York");
$event->setEnd($end);

$location = new Location();
$location->setDisplayName($location_add);
$event->setLocation($location);

$attendeesList = [];

$attendee = new Attendee();
$emailAddress = new EmailAddress();
$emailAddress->setAddress("info@example.com");
$emailAddress->setName("Gabriel Joly");
$attendee->setEmailAddress($emailAddress);
$attendee->setType(AttendeeType::REQUIRED);

$attendeesList[] = $attendee;

$attendee2 = new Attendee();
$emailAddress2 = new EmailAddress();
$emailAddress2->setAddress("gjoly@example.com");
$emailAddress2->setName("Gabriel Joly");
$attendee2->setEmailAddress($emailAddress2);
$attendee2->setType(AttendeeType::REQUIRED);

$attendeesList[] = $attendee2;


$event->setAttendees($attendeesList);

$response = $graph->createRequest("POST", "/me/events")->attachBody($event)->execute();
```

perfectly event send and receive in the professional outlook email address